# CSS: background image issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a background image to display when the mouse is hovered over any one of three images. Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/gefKT/, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? At the moment the background image simply doesn't display when you hover any of the three circular images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>SVG Included with <object> tag</title>

<style>
.center {
text-align: center;
}

#images:hover {
background-image: url(http://ubuntuone.com/1SRrDB8i8cBtpm3Smxaz5r);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <div id="images">
            <td class="center"><object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/5b5ZUS86nHAffWiOirDwFr">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/12qOaTGCZYzQtqFJpaGbPV" alt="" />
                </object></td>
            <td class="center"><object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/7Ur09JXlGVvF2GhXFbLXlx">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/54AaqhQUU8npACF2vXzKFp" alt="" />
                </object></td>
            <td class="center"><object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/6tkHm9c2r1eH9PMB9Nr3Ux">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/4CXw05d1dsSf9VhAIPNZf6" alt="" />
                </object></td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't you need to tell it the image type?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne file extension are really just for simple filesystems (and humans), if the web-server responds with the correct mime type then the browser will do the right thing

Comment: look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gefKT/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#images` div contains nothing thus has no dimensions and therefore can never be hovered over. You need to place your three images **inside** this div.

Answer (score 2):

If I was you I would change the CSS as follows:

```
<style>
.center {text-align:center;}
.boxy:hover {box-shadow:0 0 5px #000; border-radius:50%;}
</style>
```

And add the `.boxy` class to the object you have declared. Border Radius is much cleaner than to use an image (one more asset to load). You can use the actual image approach you wanted if you want this to work on IE8 and below.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gefKT/9/

Comment: Thank you Marco, very useful to know.